# textures error when compiling c + + project / Open GL

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opengl, textures

I am having a problem to compile a program made by me.

The problem is that in Visual C + + 2010 is the IDE I use, when I compile in Debug or Release mode, everything is displayed well (I'm working with Open GL and textures).

The problem is when I have the exe of my program and try to run the OpenGL window is blank.

Testing long I realized that if I did not load the texture, everything is displayed correctly.

Now my question (bearing in mind that the path is relative or texture that is correct) that the exe file does not load properly and the texture does when compiled from Visual C + + 2010?

Do not give any error as to know what is the problem.

I tried everything .. paths are correct, the texture exists in the same directory where the exe should look. It can not be ... and most strange is that from the visual c + + program (not the exe) works correctly.

Comment: It's possible that your program is silently failing to load a required DLL.  When you run an EXE from Visual Studio, you'll have extra information in your PATH, and Windows will use that when searching for DLLs.  Assuming that OpenGL itself is working fine, I should ask: what image format is your texture and how are you loading it?

Comment: Can you check "working directory" and "debugging directory" in your project settings?

Comment: Paddy is probably correct. What you can do to double check is first try copying the dlls into the same directory as your exe. If that doesn't work look up how to use GlGetError, it is very helpful for getting debugging information out from GL.

Answer (score 0):

When starting an application from Visual Studio, the applications execution path is the one, where your source code is located (one folder deeper than the .sln file).
Did you copy-paste your exe from the "Release" folder into the folder, where your textures are located? If not, try to do so. That's how I usually test my application before releasing it.
Another cause might be that your application has a bug in it.
It could be something like a pointer overwriting data, deleting freed memory or writing out of bounds of an array. All that can cause that an application simply doesn't work when being run without the debugger.
The reason for that is, that the memory layout is different between debug- and release mode.
I had such problems alot.
Is your application multithreaded? If yes, that can also be a reason why it's failing.